# Ionic 2 Central Rounded Tab

Tags: css, user-interface, mobile, ionic2, user-experience

I'm developing a Ionic 2 app with tab navigation as described in Ionic's documentation at http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#tabs-icon-text

[image]

The tab bar has 5 tabs, and I'd like to stand out the central tab making it rounded like in the image below.

I don't see any standard way provided by the framework to do that, what would be the simplest way to achieve that with CSS?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Ionic 4 latest then following code will do perfect job without using any extra css

```
<ion-tabs>

  <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
    <ion-tab-button tab="tab2" >
      <ion-icon name="cog"  color="secondary"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label  color="secondary">Settings</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="tab1">
      <!-- <ion-icon name="cog" color="secondary"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label color="secondary">Settings</ion-label> -->
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="tab3">
        <ion-icon name="information-circle" color="secondary"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label color="secondary">About</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>
  </ion-tab-bar>

</ion-tabs>
<ion-fab vertical="bottom" horizontal="center" slot="fixed">
    <ion-fab-button color="secondary" (click)="gotoHome()">
        <ion-icon name="Home"></ion-icon>
    </ion-fab-button>
</ion-fab>
```

As fab will be on top of tab button it wont work for navigation, hence you can add routing to it. what I did was added a gotoHome function and it look like:

```
export class TabsPage {
  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  gotoHome(){
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/tabs/tab1')
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I implemented this, but this is creating issue when Keyboard is open, scroll fab button.

Answer (score 2):

If you're having 5 tabs in your ion-tabs component, you can target the third tab element with the class .tab-button within ion-tabs and style it any way you want.

Keep in mind that, by default, Ionic applies different styles to its components depending on the device's operating system. When you write your custom SCSS rules, make sure to target all styles modes as well. I don't know what your particular scenario is, but you can always force the app to run in a specific mode (md, ios, windows) and all components will look the same across operating systems. By doing that you can achieve consistency in the look and feel of your app and you will only have to target one style mode.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ion-fab inside ion-tab tag :

```
<ion-tabs>
<ion-tab tabIcon="icon-1"></ion-tab>
<ion-tab tab-icon="icon-2"></ion-tab>
<ion-tab tab-icon="don't mention any icon"></ion-tab>
<ion-fab>
   <button ion-fab center bottom style="background: url("set the url of your round svg icon");"></button>
</ion-tab>
<ion-tab tabIcon="icon-3"></ion-tab>
<ion-tab tabIcon="icon-4"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

NB : you have to not put icon to the tab-icon because it will be replaced by the fab button.

This solution works with ios version without causing any problem with position fixed common issue.

Hope that will be helpfull :)